# What functions map points from unit sphere to unit sphere?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, spheres, spherical-geometry

I am looking for examples of $f:\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\to\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

The obvious one is:

$f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{Wx}$ where $\mathbf{W}$ is orthogonal and $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

Are there other functions which have an explicit analytic form that map points from unit sphere to unit sphere?

Comment: Your second example is the identity. As to more examples, define $f_n$ on the unit circle in the complex plane by $f_n(z) = z^n$ for any integer $n$, then go to higher dimensions via suspension.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake and have updated the question.

Comment: @HansEngler You can also do the same with the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^4$ and quaternions.

Comment: On $\mathbb S^2$, the Möbius transformations are suitable. They are even meromorphic if you identify $\mathbb S^2\simeq \overline{\mathbb C}$.

Comment: simple addition to (x,y,...) will do the job